# Canyon Speedmax rear bottle mount

Tags: triathlon, canyon

I've noticed a few of the pro's in triathlon using a larger rear bottle mount on the seat posts of canyon speedmax's, Sam Laidlows: https://www.instagram.com/p/CxQ37VKProf/ and Chelsea Sodaro had it on at the weekend too. Seen a few others have them.

I've messaged Canyon but they couldn't point me toward who makes them.

Does anyone know the benefits other than looking cool and know anyone who does make them? I've tried to search google but either its top secret or I'm rubbish at putting searches together.

Cheers

Comment: “Looking cool” -> quite debatable. They also are terrible to hold and drink from.

Comment: I think they look cooler and I have the normal rear mount from Canyon now and it’s perfectly fine to drink from? Must be a benefit if pros are going to the effort to make them

Answer (score 1):

Here are some better quality pics of the bike:
https://www.triathlete.com/gallery/2023-ironman-world-championship-nice-bike-sam-laidlows-speedmax-cfr/?scope=anon

With the bodgy paintjob on the metal piece and what seems like 3d printed side panels it is most likely some DIY prototype.
Probably they hope to get some aero benefits.

[image: https://www.triathlete.com/gallery/2023-ironman-world-championship-nice-bike-sam-laidlows-speedmax-cfr/?scope=anon]

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little different than the one posted in the question.
[image]
A little less bulky.

Canyon calls it "[Canyon GP0024-01 Speedmax Tri Bottle Holder](https://www.canyon.com/en-co/canyon-gp0024-01-speedmax-tri-bottle-holder/134408.html)"
They also have the "[Canyon Speedmax Seat Post Bottle Adapter](https://www.canyon.com/en-co/gear/accessories/bike-accessories/bottle-cage/canyon-speedmax-seat-post-bottle-adapter/10006351.html)"

The benifits Canyon claims are:

1. Aero position
2. Pro tested
3. Lightweight
4. Compatibility- Work perfectly with Canyon Cage SF cages and all cages with a 64mm screw interface

The only benifit I see is that it provides another alternative for mounting a bottle.

There are other seatpost bottle mounts. There are even double bottle mounts behind the seat. There is one that mounts to the seat rails so it does not matter what shape the seatpost is.
[image]

Google "bicycle seatpost bottle mount"